# loop throught 2 arrays and grab the beginning of a value and match it to a key in the second array

Tags: php, arrays, match

hey guys i have a array such as

```
 $return = array(
    'GPPZ20'=>'5.00',
    'GPPZ45'=>'10.00',
    'GPPZ75'=>'15.00',
    'GPPZH20'=>'5.00',
);
```

i also have a array thats

```
 [0] => Array
    (

        [main_company] => Marketing
        [code] => GPPZH20XSYDLDJ
        [company] => All Companies
    )

[1] => Array
    (

        [main_company] => Some Company
        [code] => XHJDOJSHHJYD
        [company] => All Companies

    )
```

and so on

what i need to do is grab the code value from the second array and check if any of the first few characters match any of the ones in the return array and if so grab the value from the return array.

I can specify the first 5 characters or 6 because the keys in the return array can be any number but they are always the beginning of the the code.

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im trying to do if(array_key_exists($code, $return)) but how do i do it so that it says if the array key is similar to the code and not exact match since only the first few characters should match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

```
foreach ( $data as $v ) {
    foreach ( $return as $k => $f ) {
        if (strpos($v['code'], $k) === 0) {
            printf("%s %s %f \n", $v['main_company'], $v['code'], $f);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Marketing GPPZH20XSYDLDJ 5.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already a code value from your second array, cut off the first part of it.

```
$code = $array[0]['code'];
$str = substr($code, 0, 5);

foreach($return as $key=>$element){
    if($key==$str){
         echo $element;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is im doing a loop inside of a loop 

to get the $code i have to do a loop then I have to do another loop inside of that for the $key=>$element loop

Comment: @Yevo so what is the problem?

Comment: well when i do the first loop and get the code its fine then inside that when i do foreach($return as $key=>$element and i print the $code it prints each one multiple times over and over

Comment: foreach($return as $key=>$value) {
                if (strpos($code, $key)!==false) {
                    echo $value . "<br />";
                }
            }